# Silverlight GetTemplateChild of control within control returns null

Tags: silverlight, templates, datepicker

I'm trying to add an indicator (I'm using TextBlock) to the datepicker control.

Visually it works but I can't get the control via GetTemplateChild. I assume it's something to do with the fact that the TextBlock control I added is in the DatePickerTextBox style template as opposed to the DatePicker style template.

I've tried DefaultStyleKey (although I don't think this makes sense as it's the TextBox control within DatePicker that's the problem) and using OnApplyTemplate and UpdateLayout on the TextBox control.

Here's a snippet of the Dictionary.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="Ind_DatePickerTextBoxStyle" TargetType="primitives:DatePickerTextBox">
   ...
   <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <TextBlock x:Name="Indicator" Text="*" Style="{StaticResource IndicatorStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

...

<!--datepicker style snippet-->

<primitives:BF_DatePickerTextBox 
   x:Name="TextBox" 
   SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" 
   Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
   BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
   BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
   Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
   Grid.Column="0" 
   Style="{StaticResource Ind_DatePickerTextBoxStyle}" />
```

Comment: What code is failing? Arr you trying to create a new control or use the toolkit control?

Comment: Sorry, lazy posting...

In the OnApplyTemplate I'm doing a GetTemplateChild.

My work around (which I'm ok with but I'd still like to know if I can get GetTemplateChild to work) is to do a VisualTreeHelper traverse through the children at the point when I want to actually do something with my Indicator (at that point it can be found...though GetTemplateChild still returns null).

Answer (score 0):

[GetTemplateChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.gettemplatechild%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) can only be used from "your control" to get a control defined in it's [control]template. When you have defined a control and given it a style you can use GetTemplateChild

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    override OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        var textbox = GetTemplateChild("TextBox");
    }
}

<Style TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
              <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

So in this example I was able to use GetTemplateChild to get the TextBox child inside the control because I was accesings my [control]template. I cannot use GetTemplateChild to get the TextBox from another control that uses MyCustomControl. Only MyCustomControl can use GetTemplateChild to get the TextBox.

Now I can extend MyCustomControl to do the same

```
public class MyOtherCustomControl : MyCustomControl
{
    override OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        var textbox = GetTemplateChild("TextBox");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I get what you're saying...in my case it's a nested template control.

i.e. datepicker has a content template which hosts datepickertextbox and it's the latter that I've modified in the style.

Comment: That is not possible. You can only get "your own children". You cannot get your grandchild. To get nested children you can use VisualTreeHelper static method GetChild